# Drupal 7 Views 3 user:current filter is missing?

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views

I'm trying to filter a view to display only nodes of the current user.
Filter by user:current  is missing however, where can it be found/enabled?

I must be missing something simple.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

In Drupal 7, Views 3, you must add the Relationship of `Content: Author` on the right side under the `Advanced` settings.  Once you've added that relationship, you will be able to see the `User: Current` filter.

Answer (score 7):

You can use another method without require any relationship.
in `Advanced` settings add `Contextual filters`  select `Content: Author uid` and in settings of it select `Provide default value` ,in `type` selectbox  choose `User ID from logged in user`

Comment: Couldn't anyone then put whatever UID they wanted in the URL and ignore your default setting?

Comment: User ID from logged in user is based on the user id of the current logged in user. It reads it from the global $user object and has nothing to do with the ur.

Comment: Is there any advantage to using this method over the relationship method? Is it more efficient or something like that?

Comment: after this step what should i do ?