# Drupal 7 Views Restrict to uid of current user

Tags: drupal-7

I have a bugs view which shows all the bug content types. My questions is, how can I limit the view to only show bugs that have assigned_to equal to the logged in user?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a filter... when you edit the view...

add filter for the current user...

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7420031/drupal-7-vews-3-usercurrent-filter-is-missing/7420924#7420924 for more info on how to add this filter

Answer (score 0):

You need to establish a relationship between your bug content type and the logged in user in the views.Once you establish the relationship the set the appropriate filters as logged in user.
Hope this helps.